# Php Bulk insert

Tags: php, bulkinsert, output

I have the code with php using bulk insert.,I run the code and there is no error., The Problem there is no OUTPUT with this code and blank page/screen appear .. All I want to do is to have the Output with the page and with the database using this code ..

```
 <?php

     $dbh = odbc_connect(
           "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=.;Database=ECPNWEB", 
           "sa", "ECPAY");




 if (($handle = fopen("c:\\tblmcwd.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, "|")) !== FALSE) {
         if (count($data) == 10) {
             $sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMCWD] (
                         [ID], 
                         [ConsumerCode], 
                         [ConsumerName], 
                         [AccountStatus], 
                         [AccountNumber], 
                         [DueDate], 
                         [CurrentBill], 
                         [PreviousBill], 
                         [TotalDiscount], 
                         [TotalGrossAmountDue]
                     ) VALUES (
                         ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
                     )";

             $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
             $stmt->bindValue(1, $data[0]);
             $stmt->bindValue(2, $data[1]);
             $stmt->bindValue(3, $data[2]);
             $stmt->bindValue(4, $data[3]);
             $stmt->bindValue(5, $data[4]);
             $stmt->bindValue(6, $data[5]);
             $stmt->bindValue(7, $data[6]);
             $stmt->bindValue(8, $data[7]);
             $stmt->bindValue(9, $data[8]);
             $stmt->bindValue(10, $data[9]);
             $stmt->execute();
         }
     }
     fclose($handle);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: You don't echo here anything??? so there will be no output

Comment: @MarcMeesters How can I echo the data/textfile in the form if there will no successful database transaction?please help men with this matter MArc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
....

$sql = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblMCWD] (
                     [ID], 
                     [ConsumerCode], 
                     [ConsumerName], 
                     [AccountStatus], 
                     [AccountNumber], 
                     [DueDate], 
                     [CurrentBill], 
                     [PreviousBill], 
                     [TotalDiscount], 
                     [TotalGrossAmountDue]
                 ) VALUES (
                     :ID, :ConsumerCode, :ConsumerName, :AccountStatus, :AccountNumber, :DueDate, :CurrentBill, :PreviousBill, TotalDiscount, TotalGrossAmountDue
                 )";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $data[0]);
$stmt->bindParam(':ConsumerCode', $data[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':ConsumerName', $data[2],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':AccountStatus', $data[3],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':AccountNumber', $data[4],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':DuaDate' , $data[5],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':CurrentBill', $data[6],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':PreviousBill', $data[7],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':TotalDiscount', $data[8],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':TotalGrossAmountDue', $data[9],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

if(!$stmt){    // Check if the query executed succesfull, if not, print the data...
    $printedString = "ID: %1$s ConsumerCode: %2$s ConsumerName: %3$s"; // and so on....
    $printedString = sprintf($printedString , $data[0],$data[1],$data[2]); // and so on...
} else{
    echo "Everything executed succesfully!<br />";
}
```

More info can you find here: [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)
And here: [Link 2](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)
And here: [Link 3](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Use `PDO::PARAM_STR` for strings and `PDO::PARAM_INT` for an integer, and give it an try

Comment: Thanks for the help I think the binvalue function is not supported in the ODBC.,I read some articles that there are some bugs with it..so I want now is to find the equicvalent function of that bindvalue.thanks again for the reply..

Comment: I still having the same error saying that ..
     Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a      non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ecpay\bulk.php on line 29

Comment: is it okay to use PDO even that I am using only ODBC?

Comment: @KristianHernanC.Manuel As far as i know, isn't it an problem. It is secure. But i'm nog an expert in it...